# properties of transformations inbetween quotient modules

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ and $R$-left module and $U, V$ submodules of $M$. I want to show that

$$f: M/U \cap V \to M/U \oplus M/V, m + U \cap V \mapsto (m + U, m + V)$$

and

$$g: M/U \oplus M/V \to M/(U+V), (m + U, n + V) \mapsto m - n + U + V$$

are two well-defined linear transformations, and that f is injective, g is surjective and $\ker g = Im f$.

Thanks in advance. I'm not quite used to working with constructions like these, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave well-defined and linear to you since I don't like to show those two.
To show $f$ is injective, note if $x\in M/(U\cap V)$ with $f(x)=(0,0)$ then $x\in U$ and $x\in V$. So $x\in U\cap V$, i.e. $x=0\in M/(U\cap V)$.

To show $g$ is surjective, note for $x\in M/(U+V)$ we can take $(x+U,0+V)$ so that $f(x+U,0+V)=x+U+V$.

Take an element $m+(U\cap V)$. Then $f(m+(U\cap V))=(m+U, m+V)$. Now $g(m+U, m+V)=m-m+U+V= U+V$ so that $\operatorname{im}(f)\subset\ker(g)$. And you need to show the reverse inclusion.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that definitely helped. Regarding the other inclusion... if $(m + U, n + V)$ with $g(m + U, n + V) = 0 + U + V$. Then $m - n + U + V = 0 + U + V = 0 + U + 0 + V = m + U - n + V$, I think. Does this already implicate that $m + (U + V) = n + (U + V)$? And if I'm not mistaken, then $U \cap V \subseteq U + V$, so therefore $m + (U \cap V) = n + (U \cap V) => (m + U, n + V) \in im(f)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @moran Yes, $m-n+(U+V)=(U+V) \implies m+(U+V)=n+(U+V)$. But I do not think since $U\cap V \subseteq U+V$ we have $m+(U+V)=n+(U+V)\implies m+(U\cap V)= n+ (U\cap V)$ for take the $\mathbb{Z}$-modules $U= 2\mathbb{Z}$, $V=4\mathbb{Z}$, $m=1$ and $n=3$. This gives a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the first is clearly well-defined, for if $m_1 + (U\cap V)$ and $m_2 + (U \cap V)$ are representatives of the same class, then $m_1 - m_2 \in (U \cap V) \subset U$, so $m_1 + U$ and $m_2 + U$ represent the same class in $M/U$, and a similar argument works for $V$.

Can you run with that to show that the second is well-defined?